# How to prevent certain usernames from being registered?

Tags: user-registration, username

How can i prevent or blacklist a list of usernames that i don't want users to register with?

And can I add a message if they try to register with one of those names that says 'this username has been reserved'

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are plugins that do this, for example, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-usernames/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict partially matching usernames see this post: [Restrict partially matching usernames](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257667/restrict-partially-matching-usernames)