# Restrict partially matching usernames

Tags: user-registration

I've been looking and looking for a solution for my problem but i have been unable to find anything.

I have found a plugin that allow me to restrict certain usernames, I found even a function but there is nothing that allows me to restrict partially matching usernames, there is nothing to prevent users to register under names like "joeadmin" or "seanadmin" and etc.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent users to register anything that contain "admin" and other prohibited words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`validate_username`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/validate_username/) filter hook that is used by [`validate_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/validate_username/) which is in turn used by [`register_new_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_new_user/).

So you can disallow usernames containing `admin` or other prohibited terms:

```
add_filter( 'validate_username', 'wpse257667_check_username', 10, 2 );
function wpse257667_check_username( $valid, $username ) {
    // This array can grow as large as needed.   
    $disallowed = array( 'admin', 'other_disallowed_string' );
    foreach( $disallowed as $string ) {
        // If any disallowed string is in the username,
        // mark $valid as false.
        if ( $valid && false !== strpos( $username, $string ) ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

You can add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file or (preferably) [make it a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

### References

- [`validate_username` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/validate_username/)
- [`validate_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/validate_username/)
- [`register_new_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_new_user/)
- [Writing a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Comment: It worked. Thank you so so much. I've breaking my head trying to find a solution and given how hard it may to describe this problem google wasn't much of a help.

And to the jerk who downvoted my thread he can go suck my d***.

Answer (score 1):

@pat-j beat me to it by a minute, but I'll elaborate that you can use a reg ex as well:

```
add_filter( 'validate_username', 'wpse257667_check_username', 10, 2 );
function wpse257667_check_username( $valid, $username ) {
    if($valid){
        $matches = null;
        $returnValue = preg_match('/(admin)/i', $username, $matches);
        return empty($matches) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution worked perfectly, but in case other decide to use yours or maybe I'll do that too, how do I add more restricted words?

Comment: you could expand the regex or make multiple ones for more complex validation

Comment: I went with `strpos()` rather than `preg_match()` mainly because I didn't feel the use case required regular expressions. [Also, `preg_*` functions are more "expensive" than simpler string functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6433513/1094518)